# Does Oracle optimize OR conditions?

Tags: sql, oracle

I've faced a strange issue. Assume we have a query

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE STATUS = 'issued'  
AND ((TRANSACTIONDATE = :to_date AND TYPE = 'A') 
    OR (TRANSACTIONDATE >= :from_date AND TRANSACTIONDATE < :to_date AND TYPE = 'M'))
```

This query runs well for some combinations of parameters. However if I pass 04/03/2013 as from_date and 04/04/2013 as end_date, I see only rows that satisfy second part of condition

```
(TRANSACTIONDATE >= :from_date AND TRANSACTIONDATE < :to_date AND TYPE = 'M')
```

On another DB instance this issue is not reproducible. So I presume it appears because of some Oracle settings. Am I right?

Comment: Check the execution plan.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name What should I look for there?

Comment: Are all your dates stored without time part?  Did you pass parameters without time part (unlike sysdate)?

Comment: Are you sure there actually exists a row with `TRANSACTIONDATE = '04/04/2013' AND TYPE = 'A' AND STATUS = 'issued'`? Did you store hours/munutes/seconds as well?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff All the dates are stored without time and parameters were entered without time either.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic yes, if I run this query for one single day 04/04/2013, I see 3 rows in output

Comment: What is the type of column `TRANSACTIONDATE`?  Date or string?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff DATE